# Change line in JS file in a post-build event (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, post-build-event

I have a JS file that has a path field that needs to be updated on deployment. I don't see that post build events allow the replacement of text or a full line by themselves, so I created a batch file to do so. However, I'm getting some odd errors.

Trying to replace the strings using a batch with powershell throws errors with the single quotes being escaped:

```
powershell -Command "(gc Utility.js) -replace 'var applicationRoot = \'\/WebApplication;\'', 'var applicationRoot = \'\';' | Out-File -encoding ASCII myFile.txt"
```

Taking out the single quotes to see if it will at least run gives an unidentified error:

```
powershell -Command "(gc Utility.js) -replace 'var applicationRoot = \/WebApplication;', 'var applicationRoot = ;' | Out-File -encoding ASCII myFile.txt"
```

I'm calling it as a post build event:

```
call "$(SolutionDir)Scripts\ChangeJSFile.bat"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please consider upvoting or accepting any answers you found helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd do this a bit differently.

Assume you have a Powershell script named _PostBuild.ps1 in the root of the project where Utility.js lives. That .ps1 script has the following contents:

```bsh
param(
    [string] $pathToJsFile,
    [string] $toReplace = "var applicationRoot = '/WebApplication';",
    [string] $replaceWith = 'var applicationRoot = ;'
)

$fileContent = Get-Content -Path $pathToJsFile
$newContent = $fileContent.Replace($toReplace, $replaceWith)
Set-Content -Path $pathToJsFile -Value $newContent
```

Then, assume that the aforementioned project has a post-build actions such as the below:

```bsh
Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command "$(ProjectDir)\_PostBuild.ps1" -pathToJsFile "$(ProjectDir)\Utility.js"
```

That will allow you to perform a string replace on Utility.js on successful build.

Obviously, you may want to make some edits to the post-build action based on your project structure.

Answer (score 1):

It was a slight nightmare but I think I have a solution for you. Basically the only issue was where you were escaping.

```
powershell -Command "(gc Utility.js) -replace \"var applicationRoot = '/WebApplication;'\", \"var applicationRoot = ';'\" | Out-File -Encoding ascii myFile.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problematic part is passing the innermost single quotes literally to PowerShell. Literal quotes inside of quotes of the same type will need some kind of escape. You have that case here since your `-replace` components are surrounded by single quotes but are intending to match literal single quotes. In those cases, you can simply use two single quotes, which escapes one single quote.

```
powershell -Command "(gc Utility.js) -replace 'var applicationRoot = ''/WebApplication;''', 'var applicationRoot = '''';' | Out-File -encoding ASCII myFile.txt"
```